# JavaScript: Событие до загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, dom

Я JS только начинаю изучать. Итак, поправьте если я что то не так понял. Есть такой jquery код:

`$(document).ready(function () {...});`.

Я так понял это событие , которое стартует после загрузки html кода. Мне нужно вписать код в событие до загрузки html и всего прочего. Я понимаю что самый простой способ это херакнуть где нибудь посреди html - `<script>...</script>`, но это как то не эстетично выглядит =) Я использовал следующий код:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {...});
```

Верно ли я написал? Если нет, то как правильно?

Comment: Что конкретно Вы сделать пытаетесь?

Comment: @Pleshevskiy, Прелоадер. Как только контент загружен он должен скрыться

Comment: Так чем `$(document).ready` не устраивает?

Comment: @Pleshevskiy, но код же тогда будет выполняться как только контент будет загружен. Там просто есть пара вещей в коде которые должны выполняться до загрузки контента

Comment: Не понимаю о чем речь. Прелоадер обычно делается на чистом css. Если у Вас на js то в самый конец тега `body` кладем скрипт и можно вызывать без `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Pleshevskiy, вот я дибил. Сайт просто начал писать давно. Ща, просто решил начать оптимизировать код. Мне же нужно его скрывать после загрузки страницы, а никак не ДО. Всё заканчиваю. Надо спать ложится. А как прелоадер сделать на чистом css? Скрыть его как после загрузки контента?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38650/discussion-between---and-pleshevskiy).

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно вписать код в событие до загрузки html и всего прочего.

Прописываете в `head`

```
 <script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

В файле `file.js` без оберток `DOM ready` пишите.

```
$(window).on('click', '.element', function() {
   // some code
});
```

Данное событие будет всегда срабатывать на элементы с классом `.element`, даже в случае динамического добавления элемента.

Как этот подход прогрессировал в различных версиях `jQuery`:

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+, deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

P.S Событие `click` замените на необходимое, можно через пробелы.